# Magento 2 - Programmatically update the flat rate shipping method price in checkout

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

I want to set a custom rate for the flat rate shipping method programmatically in frontend checkout. I have override the file `Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate::collectRates()` function but not worked this solution.Which file i have to modify or is there any event is available or any plugin?

Comment: can you please update your question with what you have done so far.

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar i just override the file without adding any customisation, but flatrate showing incorrect rate in frontend. So i just reverted the change. I think overriding of the file will not work.

Answer (score 2):

There was a private function `getShippingPrice()` in the file `Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Flatrate`

i have override this method also and its now working fine.